# Elastic Search 5.x Nest Multiple Queries C#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm using C# with those nuget packeges;

```
  <package id="Elasticsearch.Net" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="NEST" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="net462" />
```

What I want to do here, **I want to get "white" items in price range 2000 - 3000. It's a simple request for a search api, am I right ?**

So I wrote a code for this. Here it is;

```
private static void Search(IElasticContext elasticContext, string indexName)
    {
        IQueryContainer termQueryContainer = new QueryContainer();
        termQueryContainer.Term = new TermQuery
                                  {
                                      Field = new Field("description"),
                                      Value = "white"
                                  };

        IQueryContainer rangeQueryContainer = new QueryContainer();
        rangeQueryContainer.Range = new NumericRangeQuery
                                    {
                                        Field = new Field("price"),
                                        LessThanOrEqualTo = 3000,
                                        GreaterThanOrEqualTo = 2000
                                    };

        //Should get 2 items.

        SearchRequest<Product> searchRequest = new SearchRequest<Product>(indexName, typeof(Product))
                                               {
                                                   Size = 10,
                                                   From = 0,
                                                   Query = (QueryContainer) rangeQueryContainer,
                                                   PostFilter = (QueryContainer) termQueryContainer
                                               };

        EsSearchResponse<Product> response = elasticContext.Search<Product>(searchRequest);

        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusMessage);

        if (response.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (Product product in response.Documents)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Id: {0} | Name: {1}", product.Id, product.Name);
            }
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work because request has been successfull but there is no document(s) in the result, but I have. I can see the docs with Sense plugin.

If I combine two queries, nest will throw exception in runtime ( Says: "QueryContainer can only hold a single query already contains a TermQuery" ). Here it is;

[image: Nest throws exception]

Also, I can't use fluent api, because I pass the parameters to my repository-like function;

```
    EsSearchResponse<Product> response = elasticContext.Search<Product>(searchRequest);
```

How can I combine two simple queries ( search in description field & price range between 2000-3000 ) in SearchRequest of Nest dll. And what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you're trying to do is form a compound query from two queries, where both queries must be satisfied by a document in order for it to be considered a match. [A `bool` query is used to combine queries in this manner](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html), using the `must` clause to specify both queries must be satisfied. Here's an example, with the object initializer syntax

```
var client = new ElasticClient();
var indexName = "index-name";
var mustClauses = new List<QueryContainer>();

mustClauses.Add(new TermQuery
{
    Field = new Field("description"),
    Value = "white"
});

mustClauses.Add(new NumericRangeQuery
{
    Field = new Field("price"),
    LessThanOrEqualTo = 3000,
    GreaterThanOrEqualTo = 2000
});

var searchRequest = new SearchRequest<Product>(indexName)
{
    Size = 10,
    From = 0,
    Query = new BoolQuery { Must = mustClauses }
};

var searchResponse = client.Search<Product>(searchRequest);
```

With the `range` query, a document is either a match for the query clause or not, so we can forgo a score being calculated for the query by adding it as a `bool` query `filter` clause

```
var indexName = "index-name";
var mustClauses = new List<QueryContainer>();
var filterClauses = new List<QueryContainer>();

mustClauses.Add(new TermQuery
{
    Field = new Field("description"),
    Value = "white"
});

filterClauses.Add(new NumericRangeQuery
{
    Field = new Field("price"),
    LessThanOrEqualTo = 3000,
    GreaterThanOrEqualTo = 2000
});

var searchRequest = new SearchRequest<Product>(indexName)
{
    Size = 10,
    From = 0,
    Query = new BoolQuery 
    { 
        Must = mustClauses,
        Filter = filterClauses
    }
};

var searchResponse = client.Search<Product>(searchRequest);
```