# c# nest: how to dynamically append elasticsearch search queries to multi search nest query?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Currently, we have fixed 3 search queries in our multi-search query. The code looks like:

```
var results = elasticClient.MultiSearch(a => a
                           .Search<StockBaseEntity>(s => s
                           .Type("<docType>")
                           .Index(<indexName>)
                           .Take(<count>)
                           .Query(qq => qq
                           ...
                           .Search<StockBaseEntity>(s => s
                           .Type("<docType>")
                           .Index(<indexName>)
                           .Take(<count>)
                           .Query(qq => qq
                           ....
                           .Search<StockBaseEntity>(s => s
                           .Type("<docType>")
                           .Index(<indexName>)
                           .Take(<count>)
                           .Query(qq => qq
                           ....
```

All three search queries have some different query parameters, for example, first query returns "type1" doc, second & third return "type2 and type3" docs respectively.

We want to build this multi search nest query in such a way that we can have any number of search nest queries in multi searach query (and not only 3). It could be 3/4/5 or any number of search queries based on some condition. This can be achived if we can append search queries to multisearch? can we do this?

I read [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/1.x/multi-search.html) article but can't get same for nest version 5.X and I have no clue how to write query with QueryContainer?

Comment: [MultiSearchApiTests](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/5.5/src/Tests/Search/MultiSearch/MultiSearchApiTests.cs) from NEST tests project should put some light on your question.

Comment: I have done till this part. I have my queries in "fluent sytax". How do I put fluent query in "new QueryContainer()"? (as converting everything to OIS will take too much efforts)

Comment: @Rob: any idea? I have posted new question for this.. may be you will get some details at this link:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999703/how-to-write-fluent-syntax-query-in-querycontainer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42614654/1876572 take a look at this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `MultiSearchRequest` and combine it with your search descriptors.

```
var multiSearchRequest = new MultiSearchRequest{};

multiSearchRequest.Operations = new Dictionary<string, ISearchRequest>();
multiSearchRequest.Operations["search1"] = new SearchDescriptor<object>().Query(q => q.MatchAll());
multiSearchRequest.Operations["search2"] = new SearchDescriptor<object>().Query(q => q.MatchAll());
multiSearchRequest.Operations["search3"] = new SearchDescriptor<object>().Query(q => q.MatchAll());

elasticClient.MultiSearch(multiSearchRequest);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: how do I move code of "ss" which is getting used inside for sort scripts too?

Comment: I don't get your question  It doesn't compile or you want to reuse it across other searches?

Comment: There was some sort script but I have modified it and seems to be working now. Thanks for your help

Comment: On the response is there a way to get the operations name?